# Kotlin with Jetpack Compose: Have to click Submit button multiple times to insert a data to the ROOM Database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I am trying to take input and insert data into Room Database.

This is my onClick funtion.

```
onClick = {
    viewModel.setNoOfQuestions(it)
    viewModel.setQuestionsSolved(date = uiState.date, noOfQuestions = uiState.noOfQuestions)
    viewModel.upsertQuestionsSolved(uiState.questionsSolved)
}
```

This is the actual Button.

```
Button(
    onClick = {
        onClick(textState.toInt())
    }
    )
{
        Text(text = "Done")
}
```

This is the upsert code in the Dao interface

```
@Upsert
suspend fun upsertQuestionsSolved(questionsSolved: QuestionsSolved)
```

This is the code in the viewModel to insert data

```
    fun upsertQuestionsSolved(data: QuestionsSolved) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dao.upsertQuestionsSolved(data)
        }
    }
```

I noticed that when I click the Done button 3 times continuously, then only the value is getting inserted in Room database.

As provided in the description

Comment: please put the output

Comment: Its kind of hard to put the output. I click the "Done" button 2 times and there is no update on the SQLite DB. When I click the button 3rd time, the DB gets updated.

Comment: I'm sorry for your problem. Have you tried to use the debugger or database inspector in android studio? Let us know if you find something interesting from there.

Comment: Yeah I got the fix. I had to use ViewModelScope.launch in the viewmodel and when I was calling the function using the viewModel instance, I had to use another coroutine. It works fine now. Hell of a problem